# How do I get the value of a textfield without posting the form

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

Is there anyway I can get the value of a text field without posting a form.
I would like to use the value somewhere else in the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use some sort of client-side scripting.

With plain old Javascript, if your text field has ID 'textField':

```
document.getElementById('textField').value;
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('#textField').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript. `textarea` elements have a `value` property that holds whatever text is in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a javascript function on any events (By example when your text field loose focus) and get the text field value by using the `value` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t=document.getElementById('textField').value;  
alert(t);
```